# Remove xml nodes with php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

How do I remove the hirearchy section from this xml using php. Below is the structure of the xml currently:

```
<xml>
    <hirearchy>
        hirearchy child nodes...
    <hirearchy/>
    <products>
        product child nodes...
    </products>
</xml>
```

I want to open the file with php, remove the hirearchy section and the save the xml file agains so it looks like this:

```
<xml>
    <products>
        product child nodes...
    </products>
</xml>
```

Comment: Well you do that by programming. Please search SimpleXML remove node and you should find the answer.

Comment: Solved as per the other question using:

$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml') or die('Error: Cannot create object');

unset($xml->hierarchy);

$xml->asXML('feed.xml');